# Where should I start to learn the internals of Blender?

Tags: development, source-code

I have tried the new blender 2.8 canidate version and am impressed so much. I would like to learn more about the internals of it. Could you guys point me some links ? I will appreciate it.

Thanks!

/BB

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/File_Structure

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/